# Change row to boolean/logical

Tags: excel

I would like to know how to change a full row's data type to boolean/logical like for example the row is full of -1 and 0 values and i want them to show as "yes" and "no"(-1 for no that is).
Thank you.

Comment: 1) you could apply custom format 2) you could use `CTRL`+`H` and replace `-1/0` with `yes/no`

Answer (score 0):

If you want actual Excel-recognised Boolean (i.e. `TRUE` or `FALSE` and recognised by `ISLOGICAL` and `TYPE` = 4), when using the Replace method suggested in the comment put in TRUE for the 0 Replace and FALSE for the -1 Replace.

However, if it doesn't matter and "yes" or "no" will suffice, then the answer in the comment above is fine.